# + (void) initialize not called (Objective C)

Tags: iphone, objective-c

My method + (void) initialized is not called and I'm very new in Objective C. The code is in the book iPhone Game Development and I have to call the method explicitly to work. The code in the .m file is that:

```
ResourceManager *g_ResManager;

@implementation ResourceManager

//initialize is called automatically before the class gets any other message, per from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145154/what-does-your-objective-c-singleton-look-like
+ (void) initialize
{
    static BOOL initialized = NO;
    if(!initialized)
    {
        initialized = YES;
        g_ResManager = [[ResourceManager alloc] init];
    }
}

...

@end
```

But in the .h file a external declaration of the variable is made:

```
extern ResourceManager *g_ResManager; //paul <3's camel caps, hungarian notation, and underscores.

@interface ResourceManager : NSObject {
   ...
}
...
@end
```

I tried everything (remove the external, put static in the .m declaration) and always get compilation errors. The code above compiles but the method initialize is never called (putted a breakpoint to see that).

Some clue?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`+initialize` is not called until you send some message to an instance of the class. Did you send a message?

One possible problem might be that you sent a message to `g_ResManager` from another portion of your code?
That won't work, because:

1. `g_ResManager` is nil at the launch time.
2. You send a message to `g_ResManager`, which is `nil`.
3. What Objective-C runtime counts as "sending a message to a class" is not what it looks syntactically in the source code, but the real object and the message sent.
4. So, in this case, `nil` gets the message, `nil` is not an instance of `ResourceManager`, so `+initialize` is not called either.

I would change your code as follows: first, in .m,

```
static ResourceManager *g_ResManager;

@implementation ResourceManager

//initialize is called automatically before the class gets any other message
+ (void) initialize
{
    static BOOL initialized = NO;
    if(!initialized)
    {
        initialized = YES;
        g_ResManager = [[ResourceManager alloc] init];
    }
}
+(ResourceManager*)sharedResourceManager
{
     return g_ResManager;
}
...

@end
```

and then in .h, I would just have

```
@interface ResourceManager:NSObject {
...
}
+(ResourceManager*)sharedResourceManager
@end
```

Then, you can always use `[ResourceManager sharedResourceManager]`.

In fact, as Rob says in the comment, you can totally do away with `+initialize` in this case. Change .m to something like

```
@implementation ResourceManager

+(ResourceManager*)sharedResourceManager
{
     static ResourceManager *g_ResManager=nil;
     if(!g_ResManager){
         g_ResManager=[[ResourceManager alloc] init];
     }
     return g_ResManager;
}
...

@end
```

This is the idiom I always use personally. But I warn you this is not completely thread safe! It should be OK as long as you call `[ResourceManager sharedResourceManager]` once before spawning threads, which I would almost always do anyway, but that's one thing to keep in mind. On the other hand, the version above using `+initialize` should be thread safe as is, thanks to the well-defined behavior of `+initialize`. See discussions in [this blog post](http://eschatologist.net/blog/?p=178).

Comment: This is exactly what was happening. Thanks very much!!! I'm from Java and always get a NullPointerException in those cases. :D
Thanks again!

Comment: Good to know it worked. Anyway, it just shows that there're so many crappy iPhone programming book written by inexperienced ones. No sane Obj-C developer would make such a global external instance variable. It's an idiom to make a `+sharedFoo` which returns the shared instance.

Comment: Tell me about it. That really makes any sense. Use the singleton pattern and declare a external variable. But because my low level of knowledge in Objective-C, left in that way. Now everything is right. No external variable anymore. Thanks again.

Comment: Yuji is absolutely correct about how +initialize works, but there's no need to use +initialize here. Just initialize g_ResManager in +sharedResourceManager if it's nil. You can even make g_ResManager a function static in that case; no need for a file static.

Comment: Yes Rob, you're perfectly right. I thought I would use as much as the original poster wrote... I will edit my point a bit.

Comment: Guys, stackoverflow rules. Many thanks for your attention. Just joined the community today and I'm very, very happy to see how people are nice here. Cheers.

Comment: extern is actually a leftover of the older C language. As you see it should be avoided in Objective-C unless you must interface with a C-based library.

Answer (score 6):

From the documentation for NSObject:

> The runtime sends initialize to each
>   class in a program exactly one time
>   just before the class, or any class
>   that inherits from it, is sent its
>   first message from within the program.
>   (Thus the method may never be invoked
>   if the class is not used.) The runtime
>   sends the initialize message to
>   classes in a thread-safe manner.
>   Superclasses receive this message
>   before their subclasses.

`+initialize` is only called before you send a class it's first message. Until you send a message to the class, the `+initialize` method is not called.

Eg:

If you call `[[MyObject alloc] init];`, `+initialize` is called on MyObject just before `alloc` is sent to MyObject.

Comment: Thanks for the answer too, Jasarien.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that when you don't allocate an object by yourself, you should retain it. Example:

```
+ (NSPredicate *)somePredicate
{
    static NSPredicate *predicate = nil;
    if (!predicate) {
        predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"status == 2"];
        [predicate retain];
    }
    return predicate;
}
```

Otherwise it doesn't survive long enough to be used a few times (the pointer still is `!nil`, but not valid any more).

Comment: This is true, but it's not an answer to the question.

Comment: Okay, I should have made this a comment. Sorry.

Comment: @EricGoldberg This method does own the retained value; it's stored in a static variable. This is correct code.